# c# array of Point

Tags: c#, arrays, point

Currently I store X and Y using

```
Point[] points1 = new Point[] { 
    new Point { X = 262, Y = 321 }, 
    new Point { X = 325, Y = 334 }, 
    new Point { X = 278, Y = 387 }
};
```

how can I set variable 'points1' globally ? so I can using loop to pull the data X and Y.

Sample Code what I've tried

```
Point[] points1 = new Point[]{};

for(int i = 0 ; i <10 ;i ++)
{
  points1 = new Point[] { new Point { X = i, Y = i++}};
}
```

but always get the last result instead of in array list.

Comment: you can set the default values at constructor in point class.

Comment: Why do you increment `i` twice, once in the declaration of your loop and once at `Y = i++`?

Comment: The for-loop body is wrong, use points1[i] = new Point {...};

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of creating a new **array** (which is of type `Point[]`) at each iteration, you should create a new **array-element** (which is of type `Point`) and put it into the array:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    points1[i] = new Point { X = i, Y = i++ };
}
```

Furthermore you are incrementing `i` twice, once in the for-loop-declaration and once when creating the new `Point`. Therefor you get the following values for your `X`- and `Y`-coords:

```
{ 0, 2, 4, 6, 8 }.
```

To create 10 points instead of only 5 you should omit one of those incrementations.

Anyway I would suggest to use a `List<Point>` instead, which is more dynamic as you can easily add and remove elements to it:

```
List<Point> points = new List<Point>();
points.Add(new Point(...));
```

Comment: sorry, was typo.. will change the x and y value later..i did try the solution and i get this error '{"Index was outside the bounds of the array."}' hmm

Comment: How did you declare the array? Of course you need something like `points = new Point[10]` before you can add data to the array.

Comment: Do you want five elements in your array or ten?

Comment: Icic!! sorry my mistake.. may i know how can i do it dynamically? without assign a fix value?

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0 ; i <10 ;i ++)
{
points1 = new Point[] { new Point { X = i, Y = i++}};
}
```

doesn't set the value of each item in the array. It reassigns points1 to be a new array each iteration. Notice that points1 is being assigned, not an element of points1. To do this, you need to assign new Point values to points1[i] instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the points for that array directly:

```
Point[] points1 = new Point[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    points1[i] =  new Point { X = i, Y = i };
}
```

If you dont have a fixed number of point you have to use List instead of array.
Here is an example:

```
List<Point> points1 = new List<Point>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) // can be any limit
{
    points1.Add(new Point { X = i, Y = i++ });
}
// you can convert to array at any time
var points = points1.ToArray();
Console.WriteLine(points1);
```

Comment: I update my answer, and now includes the lists solution as well

Answer (score 0):

```
        List<Point> points1 = new List<Point>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            points1.Add(new Point { X = i, Y = i++ });
        }
```

Comment: Do add some text/context. Code-only answers are less helpful and frowned upon! Also: I don't think he want to add a point. But using List is generally recommended..